# PHP: mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to implement a login system, and it mostly works except for this PHP script that's been returning 0:

```php
// $username_err & $password_err is empty, gets reset every time as "".

if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
    $query = "SELECT rowid, username, password FROM admin_login WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
        $param_username = $username;

            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Doesn't work here, works up until here.
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $rowid, $username, $hashed_password);

                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){

                        session_start();

                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["id"] = $rowid;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

                        header("location: index.php");

                        }else{
                           $password_err = "Invalid password";
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    $username_err = "No such account exists.";
            }
        }else{
    echo "An error occurred.";
    }

  }

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}

mysqli_close($db);
```

This never works, as it gets stuck since it doesn't meet the condition mysqli_stmt_num_rows == 1, rather it returns a 0. It does work via MySQL directly through the Workbench:

```sql
SELECT rowid, username, password FROM admin_login WHERE username = "admin";
```

does return 1 row with the matching criteria.

** EDIT: Here's my new code; **

```php
<?php
require_once "_php/login/config.php";

$username = $password = "";
$err = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
        $err = "Enter a username";
    } else {
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    if (empty(trim($_POST["password"]))) {
        $err = "Enter a password";
    } else {
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT rowid, username, password FROM admin_login WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["username"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

    if ($user && password_verify($_POST["password"], $user["password"])) {
        session_start();

        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

        header("location: index.php");
    } else {
        $err = "Wrong password";
    }
}

//end of program
```

And it throws:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in *directory*/login_script.php:25 Stack trace: #0 *directory*/login.php(2): require() #1 {main} thrown in *directory*/login_script.php on line 25

For reference, login_script is the PHP script, login is the frontend as php.

Comment: MySqli is horribly old. Have you looked at trying PDO? https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php -- Its much simpler, safer and binding params is simpler. 

Also shouldnt  $param_username = $username; be above the bind statement?

Comment: @daveBM Uhh, what?? `mysql_*` is old and should be avoided - yes. `mysqli_` (note the `i`) is perfectly fine. PDO is no more safe than MySQLi is, as long as you bind parameters (goes for both MySQLi and PDO).

Comment: @daveBM I'll take a look at PDO, but isn't MySQLi a modern successor to MySQL commands in php? Also, I did modify the code to have $param_username = $username on top of bind, doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Do you get any errors? `var_dump($stmt->error);` after `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`? What does `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` return? How do you know it executes (meaning, entering the `if` block for the execute?

Comment: Why don't you just use `$username` directly instead of creating a copy of it as `$param_username`?

Comment: @daveBM - In what way is PDO "safer" than Mysqli?

Comment: @Qirei When I added echo mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) before the if block for the comparison, I got a 0.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No real reason except I was following a tutorial. I could change $param_username to $username, doesn't really change the results.

Comment: Why is `$password = trim($_POST["password"]);` repeated twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You **never** need that useless num_rows thing. You already have a row from fetch(). Use it wherever you have an idea to use num_rows.
2. When it's 0 (or, rather, the only fetched row is false), it means your query found no rows given the input values and the current database contents. As simple as that. **This is the answer to your question.** Simple, direct and logical.
3. That said, this code three times more bloated than it needs be. See the canonical code I wrote for [checking the password using mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/password_hash). Verify your input values, the database contents and check for errors - and it would work flawless.

Comment: Please see edited comment; I did try your method, it throws an error at the moment.